# How to update a MapInfo table with chronological numbers

Tags: mapinfo

Is it possible to automatically update a column in a MapInfo table with chronological numbers (1, 2, 3 etc.).

*This is without taking a chronological number set from another table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean update a column with the row number?
If so, update it with the variable rowid.

Comment: Can you explain in simple terms how to do this?

Comment: Table > Update Column.
Choose the Table and Column to update.
In the Value box, type rowid
Click OK.